# Image pasted to Word header from clipboard via VBA is neither listed as InlineShape nor as Shape

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, shapes

I'm trying to copy an image (already an image in Excel, not a table which is then converted to an image) from an Excel sheet to a Word header. Afterwards I would like to manipulate it, e.g. scale, alignment etc.). The pasting works perfectly but I cannot select it afterwards because it is neither listed as InlineShape (which I could then convert to a shape) nor as Shape - so what is it then and how can I select it? From what I read here and on various other platforms, this **should** work but it doesn't. Am I forgetting to take care of something concerning headers?

I tried various coding approaches by now, but none works. Examples:

1)

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Backup - Do not change").Shapes("companyLogo").Copy
wdDoc.Sections(1).Headers(2).Range.Paste 'this should result in an InlineShape
Debug.Print wdDoc.InlineShapes.Count '= 0
Debug.Print wdDoc.Shapes.Count '= 0
```

2)

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Backup - Do not change").Shapes("companyLogo").Copy
wdDoc.Sections(1).Headers(2).Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=8 '=wdPasteShape
Debug.Print wdDoc.InlineShapes.Count '= 0
Debug.Print wdDoc.Shapes.Count '= 0
```

3)

```
Dim wdRng As Object
Set wdRng = wdDoc.Sections(1).Headers(2).Range
wdRng.Paste
Debug.Print wdDoc.InlineShapes.Count '= 0
Debug.Print wdDoc.Shapes.Count '= 0
```

I hope you can help me with this issue, it's driving me mad. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental issue with your code is that you're pasting it into the header, but then trying to reference it without regard to its location. Try something along the lines of:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Backup - Do not change").Shapes("companyLogo").Copy
With wdDoc.Sections(1).Headers(2).Range
  .Paste
  With .InlineShapes(1)
    .LockAspectRatio = True
    .Width = wdApp.InchesToPoints(2)
  End With
End With
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much! I had though about this, too, and I tried something similar (which I forgot to list here) but apparently I did something wrong.